# Ajustar View Swift

Tags: ios, swift2

Hola estoy terminando una aplicación el problema es que en 3.5 y 4 pulgadas se ve bien pero en 4.7 y 5.5 se ve bastante desajustada la pantalla los objetos no estaban centrados y algunos aparecían sobre puestos en mi storyboard agregue un View para ordenar la pantalla y horizontalmente se ve bien pero en horizontal no está centrado. Mi consulta es si hay alguna forma o fórmula de Constraints para centrar o si puedo hacerlo por código. ya probe todos los posibles contraints y tambien la opcion de Reset to suggested.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por código puedes hacerlo, es muy sencillo, pesado y desaconsejable. Solo tiene que obtener los tamaños de la vista, los iconos, etc y empezar ha hacer cálculos para centrarlos modificando el frame. Si no te queda centrado y estas usando autolayout, creo que hay algún constraints que te falta o te sobra, pero aquí no los vemos

Comment: por codigo debo hacer un @IBOutlet para desde el Controller hacer los cambios verdad?, se puede por codigo tambien especificar distintas dimensiones para distintos tamaños de pantalla? gracias de antemano.

Comment: si claro, sacas el tamaño con view.frame.size y a partir te hinchas a poner if

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo quieres hacer en el Storyboard, yo te diría que metas esos 4 iconos en una `UIView` contenedora, con las 4 vistas pineadas entre ellas y a los márgenes de ese contenedor.

```
------------------------------------------
|  _______|______     ________|________  |
| |              |    |                | |
|-| Localización |----|   Turismo      |-|
| |______________|    |________________| |
| ________|______     ________|________  |
| |              |    |                | |
|_|    Clima     |----| Paso Hua Hum   |-|
| |______________|    |________________| |
|_________|___________________|__________|
```

y luego a ese contenedor le pones unas constraints para centrarlo horizontalmente. Y otra para ponerlo a la altura que quieras.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]